# Getting Uncaught SecurityError when using Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, sidekiq, turbolinks

I have a Rails app where the user is allowed to upload an image. The image is processed asynchronously in a Sidekiq background job.

When a user attempts to view the image, if the image isn't available, the url will return an error.

```
GET https://cloudfront.com/photo.jpg 403 (Forbidden)
```

So I use an error handler to wait for 10 seconds, then try again.

```
img.error =>
    timer = setTimeout ( =>
            #reattempt to get image
        ), $.RETRY_IN_MILISECONDS

    $(document).on 'page:before-change', =>
        clearTimeout timer
```

Sometimes, if the user moves to another page, the user gets this javascript error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: A history state object with URL 'https://cloudfront.com/photo.jpg' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://foobar.com'.
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this/handle this? Thanks!